# Why went dovecot pop3/imap server down?

Tags: linux, email, dovecot, imap, outage

The VPS went at some point down, I am watching the log but do not understand why went down and how it could be fixed to avoid outages in the future.

The logs I have available for the time of the event:

```
- Feb 04 16:16:41 imap(jakub.elias@helpito.com): Info: Connection closed (EXAMINE finished 0.078 secs ago) in=290 out=4306
- Feb 04 16:18:25 auth: Error: passwd-file(webadmin,141.98.10.183): stat(/etc/exim/domains//passwd) failed: No such file or directory
- Feb 04 16:23:00 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<info@helpito.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=37.48.20.176, lip=46.36.37.22, mpid=8772, TLS, session=<qZdwR4S626ElMBSw>
- Feb 04 16:23:00 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<jakub.elias@helpito.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=37.48.20.176, lip=46.36.37.22, mpid=8774, TLS, session=<ZPd2R4S63KElMBSw>
- Feb 04 16:23:01 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<jakub.elias@osobnizkusenosti.cz>, method=PLAIN, rip=37.48.20.176, lip=46.36.37.22, mpid=8775, TLS, session=<2f53R4S6j6ElMBSw>
- Feb 04 16:23:01 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<info@helpito.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=37.48.20.176, lip=46.36.37.22, mpid=8779, TLS, session=<8Hp+R4S6o6ElMBSw>
- Feb 04 16:23:01 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<jakub.elias@osobnizkusenosti.cz>, method=PLAIN, rip=37.48.20.176, lip=46.36.37.22, mpid=8780, TLS, session=<lHp+R4S6pKElMBSw>
- Feb 04 16:23:01 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<jakub.elias@helpito.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=37.48.20.176, lip=46.36.37.22, mpid=8781, TLS, session=<JqWAR4S6mKElMBSw>
- Feb 04 16:23:01 imap(jakub.elias@osobnizkusenosti.cz): Info: Connection closed (UID FETCH finished 0.068 secs ago) in=337 out=1853
- Feb 04 16:23:01 imap(jakub.elias@helpito.com): Info: Connection closed (UID SEARCH finished 0.047 secs ago) in=104 out=864
- Feb 04 16:23:01 imap(jakub.elias@helpito.com): Info: Connection closed (IDLE running for 0.001 + waiting input for 0.789 secs, 2 B in + 10 B out, state=wait-input) in=27 out=720
- Feb 04 16:23:01 imap(info@helpito.com): Info: Connection closed (IDLE running for 0.001 + waiting input for 0.844 secs, 2 B in + 10 B out, state=wait-input) in=27 out=711
- Feb 04 16:23:01 imap(info@helpito.com): Info: Connection closed (UID SEARCH finished 0.076 secs ago) in=104 out=849
- Feb 04 16:23:02 imap(jakub.elias@osobnizkusenosti.cz): Info: Connection closed (IDLE running for 0.001 + waiting input for 0.988 secs, 2 B in + 10 B out, state=wait-input) in=27 out=712
- Feb 04 16:23:06 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<info@helpito.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=37.48.20.176, lip=46.36.37.22, mpid=8783, TLS, session=<vynJR4S6mqElMBSw>
- Feb 04 16:23:06 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<jakub.elias@helpito.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=37.48.20.176, lip=46.36.37.22, mpid=8786, TLS, session=<AxzSR4S6oaElMBSw>
- Feb 04 16:23:06 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<jakub.elias@osobnizkusenosti.cz>, method=PLAIN, rip=37.48.20.176, lip=46.36.37.22, mpid=8787, TLS, session=<mafSR4S6vKElMBSw>
- Feb 04 16:23:07 imap(info@helpito.com): Info: Connection closed (UID SEARCH finished 0.244 secs ago) in=140 out=945
- Feb 04 16:23:07 imap(jakub.elias@helpito.com): Info: Connection closed (UID SEARCH finished 0.136 secs ago) in=142 out=946
- Feb 04 16:23:07 imap(jakub.elias@osobnizkusenosti.cz): Info: Connection closed (UID FETCH finished 0.162 secs ago) in=460 out=2160
- Feb 04 16:23:21 imap(jakub.elias@helpito.com): Info: Server shutting down. in=5478 out=40976
- Feb 04 16:23:21 imap(jakub.elias@osobnizkusenosti.cz): Info: Server shutting down. in=10678 out=144474
- Feb 04 16:23:21 imap(info@helpito.com): Info: Server shutting down. in=5253 out=37892
- Feb 06 17:30:07 master: Info: Dovecot v2.2.36 (1f10bfa63) starting up for imap, pop3 (core dumps disabled)
- Feb 06 17:30:27 auth: Error: passwd-file(test,36.133.44.246): stat(/etc/exim/domains//passwd) failed: No such file or directory
- Feb 06 17:30:38 imap-login: Info: Login: user=<info@helpito.com>, method=PLAIN, rip=213.220.236.56, lip=46.36.37.22, mpid=15309, TLS, session=<SUUEda26fGfV3Ow4>
```

Comment: Looks like `dovecot` was instructed to use a file originally configured for `exim` (another software possibly deleted in the meantime). Ask the person who configured that, and grab the backups of the path mentioned in your log (`/etc/exim/`).

Comment: Hi anx, I do not cooperate with that person anymore (except other things, he did not know how to fix this). EXIM is installed and used for sending emails and in my understanding the issue is right with Exim, because receiving emails works as expected but sending them does not. I am now on my own and have no idea how to troubleshoot this.

Answer (score 1):

Dovecot can't find any usable list of users. I may have been at given path (`/etc/exim/domains/passwd`) or not (configuration may have been inadequately changed). Make sure you know what you are doing using Webmin or managing your server yourself.

A helpful hand of a real Linux/Unix admin might be a best choice.

You can try to start Dovecot in foreground (-F) and see exactly what's happening at startup. Be sure, what do you want it to do beforehand. E. g. is Exim working well?

Comment: Hi d.c., well, in my understanding Dovecot is for receiving emails (imap,pop3) which work as expected, I am observing issues with sending emails (for which is actually used mentioned Exim). Would it help to share with you some other log file?

Comment: Dovecot is for receiving e-mails, unless you instruct the sending e-mails part (Postfix/Exim) to allow relay only to "your" users. They need to provide credentials to use e. g. submission. The mechanism usually used for this is SASL, but it's the matter of taste of SMTP server author/admin.

Comment: I am afraid, this is very abstract for me. I do not really understand what to do to fix the issue.